# Vue Change image based on localization

Tags: vue.js, svg, vue-i18n

I'm making a website using Vue, and have added localization using vue-i18n, however there are some svg-images that also need to change with localization.

Is it possible to add the filename to the localization file like this:
`"image" : "EnglishImage.svg"`
or
`"image" : "../assets/images/price/EnglishImage.svg"`

And in the Vue something like: `<img :src="$t('image')">`

And have it change when the localization is changed?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick temporary fix I used the following steps:

1. Place the images normally into the page
2. Run project
3. Use inspect to find the path for them. (it was something like "../img/EnglishImage.c9bc8f65.svg"
4. Add these paths to the Localization files

Not the best solution, but for now it works